# Secure Gateway Client fails to recognize gatewayid or sectoken on docker run, error 401

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

When trying to execute docker container with gatewayid & sectoken, it fails with error "The Secure Gateway gateway ID was either not recognized or requires a security token to connect, error was: 401".  And yet when I manually add via the CLI, it's successful.

I suspect it's because my security token has  '--' in it.  I tried '', "", and escaping characters on command line. but nothing worked.    Fails in both Win10 and RHEL7.

Here's the console:

```
C:\Users\DebraJohnson>docker run -p 9023:9003 -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client <gateway_id>  --t <sectoken> 
IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway Client Version 1.8.0fp4
....
<press enter for the command line>
[2018-04-16 09:12:17.993] [INFO] (Client ID 1) No password provided. The UI will not require a password for access
[2018-04-16 09:12:18.008] [WARN] (Client ID 1) UI Server started. The UI is not currently password protected
[2018-04-16 09:12:18.009] [INFO] (Client ID 1) Visit localhost:9003/dashboard to view the UI.
cli> [2018-04-16 09:12:18.327] [INFO] (Client ID 13) Setting log level to INFO
[2018-04-16 09:12:18.665] [ERROR] (Client ID 13) The Secure Gateway gateway ID was either not recognized or requires a security token to connect, error was: 401
cli> [2018-04-16 09:12:18.671] [INFO] (Client ID 13) Process exiting without errors due to user or server request

cli> sectoken <sectoken>
cli> connect <gateway_id>
cli> [2018-04-16 09:12:43.095] [INFO] (Client ID 27) Setting log level to INFO
[2018-04-16 09:12:43.774] [INFO] (Client ID 27) The Secure Gateway tunnel is connected
[2018-04-16 09:12:43.868] [INFO] (Client ID xxxxxxxxxxx_Hsu) Your Client ID is xxxxxxxxxxx_Hsu 
xxxxxxxxxxx_Hsu>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a `--` as part of the security token could be the reason why you got 403 error. Can you please try regenerating the security token and connect the gateway again.

If you still have issues please open a support ticket (https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/howtogetsupport.html#getting-customer-support) where you can provide the gateway id for us to look further into this.

Comment: I suspected that the "--" was the problems.  I regenerated the token and it now works.  But that means that the problem exists in generating the token from IBM Secure Gateway Servers.  If it generates it with "--"  it will fail when initializing